# Minecraft Is Y coordinate block level measured at Head or Feet

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This is a question that has plagued me forever.

When I look at the Y coordinate and it says 60. does that mean level 60 is occupied by my head or is level 60 occupied by my feet.

Comment: I don't know why they decided to change it from showing both :/

Comment: Look down and see 'Looking at:' in debug screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the level measured at your feet. As is stated [on the Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Debug_screen)

> Y: Player's (feet) altitude in blocks (63 (62.9) is overworld sea level, 11 (10.9) is overworld lava flood level, 32 (31.9) is nether lava sea).

Comment: FYI: to prove that, simply do `/setblock ~ ~ ~ <BlockID>`. You will find that the block is placed on your feet.